# Assigning multiple variables within the same line in python

Tags: python, fibonacci

```
def fibonacci(n):

    prev = curr = 1
    yield 1
    while curr < n:
        yield curr
        #1
        prev = curr 
        curr = curr + prev 
        #or
        #2
        prev ,curr = curr, curr + prev
```

I have this fibonacci code here and I don't understand why when I assign:

```
prev = curr #first
curr = curr + prev #second

fibonacci(10)
```

results: 11248

gives a different answer then when I assign

```
prev ,curr = curr, curr + prev 

fibonacci(10)
```

results: 112358

Which gives the correct Fibonacci sequence. Can someone please explain to me why is it so?

Thank you in advance for your input.

Comment: in this first one you're bascially doing `curr = 2*curr`

Comment: Try to go line by line and write on paper the values of `curr` and `prev` in each step. Or add some debug/print lines

Answer (score 1):

what `prev, curr = curr, prev+ curr` does is similar to:

```
temp = prev + curr
prev = curr
curr = temp
```

But what you are doing is setting `curr` value to `prev` and then you are basically doing `curr = curr + curr` (because `prev` now is equal to `curr`)

Answer (score 0):

Because the second one does the operations at the same time meaning that for `curr = curr + prev` it uses your previous `prev`, not `prev = curr`

If you want a sequential assignment where the latter assignment depends on the previous, you should try the first method. The second method is WRONG!